# pyspark and kafka connection on WSL

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am following a project on youtube about :
[Realtime Data Streaming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqAcTrqKcrY&t=2897s)
I am using WSL on Windows to run this project and met this error

```
WARNING:root:kafka dataframe could not be created because: An error occurred while calling o36.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/$less$colon$less
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaSourceProvider$$validateStreamOptions(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:338)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.sourceSchema(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceSchema(DataSource.scala:233)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo(DataSource.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingRelation$.apply(StreamingRelation.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.loadInternal(DataStreamReader.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:144)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.$less$colon$less
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        ... 20 more
```

From what i found, similar answers to this is mismatch between scala and spark.
Here is what i have :
Running on Ubuntu (WSL)
I install pyspark with

```
pip install spark pyspark==3.4.1
```

From spark-shell `Using Scala version 2.12.17 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 17.0.9)`
This is the code i using for connection:

```
def create_spark_connection():
    s_conn = None

    try:
        s_conn = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName('SparkDataStreaming') \
            .config('spark.jars.packages', "com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.13:3.4.1,"
                                           "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13:3.4.1,"
                                           "org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.8.0,"
                                           "org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.4.1,"
                                           "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0-preview2,"
                                           "org.apache.spark:spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0-preview2") \
            .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'localhost') \
            .getOrCreate()

        s_conn.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
        logging.info("Spark connection created successfully!")
        print('Spark connection created successfully!')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Couldn't create the spark session due to exception {e}")

    return s_conn
```

Please let me know what i am missing.
I found there are many people have the same problem as this and there still no answers.

Comment: All of your extra packages in the config should match, so `2.12:3.4.1` (the Scala version, which is 2.12, and Spark version) rather than `2.12:3.0.0-preview2` and `2.13:..`